# Javascript How to check the length of multiple variables and return the result in an efficient way?

Tags: javascript

At the moment I have an if the condition that checks if any of the string variable lengths is greater than 2 if true check for another condition, else console.log the output.

```
var previous_data_change = 'last_changed on 10/01/2019 13:56:34';
var current_data_change= "";
var current_data_end = "";
var current_data_profile = "normal";
// check for changes
if (
    previous_data_change.length >= 2 ||
    current_data_start.length >= 2 ||
    current_data_end.length >= 2 ||
    current_data_profile.length >= 2
) {
  if (previous_data_change.includes("last_changed")) {
    console.log(`last change comments: ${previous_data_change}`)
  } 
} else {
    console.log(`no change in previous record`)
}
```

i have tried refactoring it using some,

```
var previous_data_change = 'last_changed on 10/01/2019 13:56:34';
var current_data_change= "";
var current_data_end = "";
var current_data_profile = "normal";

var filter_col = [
  previous_data_change,
  current_data_change,
  current_data_end,
  current_data_profile
];
change_boolean = filter_col.some((element) => element.length >= 2);
if (change_boolean && previous_data_change.includes("last_changed")) {
  console.log(`last change comments: ${previous_data_change}`);
} else {
  console.log("no change in previous record");
}
```

is there any way to shorten it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want any of them to be length greater than 2. You can simply merge them instead of writing 4 if conditions.

```js
var previous_data_change = 'last_changed on 10/01/2019 13:56:34';
var current_data_change= "";
var current_data_end = "";
var current_data_profile = "normal";

var string_to_check = previous_data_change + current_data_start + current_data_end + current_data_profile;

// check for changes
if (string_to_check.length < 2) {
    console.log(`no change in previous record`)
    return false;
}

if (previous_data_change.includes("last_changed")) {
    console.log(`last change comments: ${previous_data_change}`)
    return true;
}
```